# TRIGGER MYSQL NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql

I created this trigger:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Invitations` 
( `userId` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `status` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL, `userId_inv` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`userId_inv`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TRIGGER `Invitation_001_after_trig` AFTER INSERT ON `invitation_001`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
    IF ((new.userId,'001') NOT EXISTS (SELECT `userId`,`userId_inv` FROM `Invitations` 
    WHERE `userId`= new.userId AND `userId_inv` = '001' LIMIT 1))
    THEN 
    INSERT INTO `Invitations`(`userId`, `name`,`status`,`userId_inv`) 
    values (new.userId, new.name,new.status,'001'); 
    DELETE FROM `invitation_001` WHERE `status` = 'a';
    END IF;
END;
```

It did not work. I had this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'EXISTS (SELECT `userId`,`userId_inv` FROM `Invitations` WHERE
>   `userId`= new.user' at line 1

So could you help me.

I resolved the problem with this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Invitation_001_after_trig` AFTER INSERT ON `invitation_001` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO `Invitations` (`userId`, `name` ,`status` ,`userId_inv`) SELECT * FROM    
invitation_001 iv WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `Invitations` ivs WHERE ivs.`userId` = iv.`userId` AND 
ivs.`userId_inv` = iv.`userId_inv`) AND iv.`userId_inv`='001';END;
```

Now I've an other issue. I would like to execute a query from a Concat String in a trigger but until now I did not succeed so here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `InvitationS_after_trig` AFTER INSERT ON `Invitations` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    if(new.status ='c' OR new.status ='r')
    BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT("INSERT INTO", Invetations.userId,"values(new.userId,new.name,new.status,new.userId_inv);");
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
        EXECUTE stmt1; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
    END IF;
END;
```

I resolved the syntax problem but I now have an other one:

> Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

I'm using MySQL version 5.1.69.

Finally  I give up, I will resolve this problem using java Fonction

Comment: I think the error "*Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger*" is pretty clear. It's one of the (many) limits in MySQL. You will need to find a different solution.

Comment: Yes, I know . It is took me a lot of time to find a solution. I try to create a stored PROCEDURE that execute the Dynamic SQL and from a trigger I call that procedure. So What do you thing?